# Beautiful Soup: Could not extract whole unicode text

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract news titles from a news portal that is in a language other than English. But, I can't extract the whole sentence. I got only the first few words or letters of the entire text.

My code is as below.

```
res=requests.get("https://ekantipur.com/news").text
soup_ek = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
ek_ = soup_ek.find_all('div', class_='teaser offset')

    for i,news in enumerate(ek_):
        title=news.find('a').text.strip()
        print(title,i)
```

example:
Expected Output:

> २४ घण्टामा ९७ जना कोरोना संक्रमित, थप ३ को मृत्यु

What it shows:

> २४ घण्टामा ९७ जना कोरोना स

Comment: Use `title=news.find('a').text.strip().encode()
 text=title.decode(encoding) #encoding of your choice` encoding can be utf-8 or iso whatever suits use

Comment: @DataNoob It gave the same result.

Comment: It might not be an encoding problem. I could be a scraping problem.

Comment: when i run your code, it prints the expected output

Comment: Which python and OS are you using? @JonathanLeon

Comment: python 3.8.2 on a windows 10 laptop

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but confirmation the code worked for me. I tried with `.strip()` and without. Here's the test

```
res=requests.get("https://ekantipur.com/news").text
soup_ek = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
ek_ = soup_ek.find_all('div', class_='teaser offset')

for i,news in enumerate(ek_):
#     title=news.find('a').text.strip()
#     print(title,i)
    print(news.find('a').text.strip())
    print(news.find('a').text)
    print('\n')
```

The last one should be your example..

```
संघीय सरकारका कारण काम गर्न सकिएन : मुख्यमन्त्री गुरुङ
संघीय सरकारका कारण काम गर्न सकिएन : मुख्यमन्त्री गुरुङ


एमिकस क्युरीको राय : प्रतिनिधिसभा विघटनको पक्षमा एक, विपक्षमा चार
एमिकस क्युरीको राय : प्रतिनिधिसभा विघटनको पक्षमा एक, विपक्षमा चार


‘टुँडिखेल मार्च’ मा कसले के भने ?
‘टुँडिखेल मार्च’ मा कसले के भने ?


२४ घण्टामा ९७ जना कोरोना संक्रमित, थप ३ को मृत्यु
२४ घण्टामा ९७ जना कोरोना संक्रमित, थप ३ को मृत्यु
```